# how can a machine can generate a random number using some algorithm?

Tags: c++, random

we can use srand and rdrand, also we can use hardware rngs.

[https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_hardware_random_number_generators]

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_number_generation

Comment: And some processors claim to have genuine random generating hardware. See [RdRand](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RdRand) & [this blog entry](http://bootstrappingartificialintelligence.fr/WordPress3/2015/02/the-imitation-game-a-film-on-alan-turing/)

Comment: In this no details are given about true random numbers.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to check the **rdrand** instruction **[here](http://electronicdesign.com/learning-resources/understanding-intels-ivy-bridge-random-number-generator)**.

The idea is to use electrical / termic events in the machine that can be measured accurately enough and that are non deterministic.